# Spring Boot injecting Map values from .properties and .yaml using ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am noticing a difference in behavior in Spring when I attempt to inject a `Map` from a `.properties` file vs. a `.yaml` file.  I am using Spring's `ConfigurationProperties` to do this.

The files:

`products.yaml`:

```
test-service:
  products:
    1: alpha
    2: bravo
    3: charlie
```

`products.properties`:

```
test-service.products.1=alpha
test-service.products.2=bravo
test-service.products.3=charlie
```

My `ProductProperties` class that loads the properties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("test-service")
public class ProductProperties {

    private final Map<String, String> products = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Unit test `ProductPropertiesPropertiesTest`, which passes:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ProductProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:products.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ProductProperties.class)
public class ProductPropertiesPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductProperties productProperties;

    @Test
    public void testProperties() {
        assertEquals(3, productProperties.getProducts().size()); // passes
    }
}
```

Unit test `ProductPropertiesYamlTest`, which fails:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ProductProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:products.yaml")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ProductProperties.class)
public class ProductPropertiesYamlTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductProperties productProperties;

    @Test
    public void testProperties() {
        assertEquals(3, productProperties.getProducts().size()); // fails
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two tests is the source of the properties: a `.properties` file (which passes), and a `.yaml` file, which fails.

Why?

Comment: It fails _how, specifically_?

Comment: .yml file having the highest preference then .properties file and by default, spring apps use .yaml if their application.yml  available u don't need to use @TestPropertySource for that. and make sure your file name is application.yaml

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code

[TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings) `YAML` files cannot be loaded using `PropertySource` and `TestPropertySource` annotation

> @TestPropertySource is a class-level annotation that is used to configure the locations() of properties files and inlined properties() to be added to the Environment's set of PropertySources for an ApplicationContext for integration tests.

[YAML Shortcomings](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html)

> YAML files cannot be loaded by using the @PropertySource annotation. So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

So change your `yml` file name to `application.yml` and then still you need to add `@SpringBootTest` annotation on test class to bind those properties from yml file

[Loading YAML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml) Spring boot has binder utils

> To bind to properties like that by using Spring Boot’s Binder utilities (which is what @ConfigurationProperties does), you need to have a property in the target bean of type java.util.List (or Set) and you either need to provide a setter or initialize it with a mutable value.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ProductProperties.class)
//default to application.yml
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ProductProperties.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProductPropertiesPropertiesTest {

   @Autowired
   private ProductProperties productProperties;

   @Test
   public void testProperties() {
       assertEquals(3, productProperties.getProducts().size()); // passes
     }
 }
```

But for properties files `@SpringBootTest` is optional because by default SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files and adds them to the Spring Environment

Comment: If you are using JUnit 5, there’s no need to add the equivalent @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) as @SpringBootTest and the other @…Test annotations are already annotated with it.

Answer (score 0):

The properties from the `.properties` file gets loaded as you see them:

```
"test-service.products.1": "alpha"
"test-service.products.2": "bravo"
"test-service.products.3": "charlie"
```

The properties from the `.yaml` file get loaded with these names:

```
"test-service.products[1]": "alpha"
"test-service.products[2]": "bravo"
"test-service.products[3]": "charlie"
```

To load the numeric keys as nested names, not index lookups, you must quote them:

```
test-service:
  products:
    "1": alpha
    "2": bravo
    "3": charlie
```

Like in JSON: *numbers*, `true`, `false`, and `null` are special and should be quoted. Same of course goes for strings with special characters, though there is some leeway there, see e.g. [Strings in YAML - To Quote or not to Quote](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html).

Comment: I have tried your solution but it's not working. Can check here  https://github.com/pandiyan90/propertyexample.git